# How do I conditionally return information in an ArcGIS Online popup using an Arcade data expression?

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, arcade

I am formatting a pop up and have one attribute where some of the features have a value and the others are empty. I want to make it so when I click on a feature that has a notes value, it shows up in the pop up but when I click on a feature that does not have a notes value, nothing shows up. Below is what I have come up with, but it still does not work.

```
IIF($feature.NOTES != null, ret + " Notes: " + Proper($feature.NOTES), ret);
```

where ret is a variable that includes some generic formatting strings. As of now, when I click on a feature that has a note, the pop up works and reads "Notes: xyz.". But when I click on a feature that does not have a note, the pop up will still read "Notes: ".

Answer (score 1):

After some time, I was able to resolve the issue so I am posting this as an answer. I first had to create two new variables, one for the note attribute value and one for the string that I wanted to be included if there is a note. The code looked like this:

```
var note = $feature.NOTES
var n = (" Notes: " + Proper($feature.NOTES))
IIF(note == " ", ret, ret + n)
```